# How to read this below type of response in Android using retrofit ?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

**I have a post link which response back below type of json.**

{
 "response": "100100000001"
}

I want to store that response code in a variable.

Comment: Try googling for a basic retrofit tutorial. That will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: The following link explains basic usage fairly thoroughly: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit